# SQL Subqueries Returning Null Value Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to put together an SQL query for woocommerce which grabs and organizes all the data from the `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table.

I cobbled together the following based on a similar query used for grabbing gravity forms hash values:

```
SELECT order_item_id AS entryId,
    (
        SELECT meta_value
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'Name'
            AND order_item_id = entryId LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'Full Name',
    (
        SELECT meta_value
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'Email'
            AND order_item_id = entryId LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'User Email',
    (
        SELECT meta_value
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'Address'
            AND order_item_id = entryId LIMIT 1
        ) AS 'User Address'
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
WHERE meta_value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY entryId
ORDER BY entryId
```

And it seems to run fine. I've run it through MySQL and I get the results I need, but I also get a number of rows that are nothing but `NULL` values.

Is there a way to filter out the rows that are only `NULL` values using the aforementioned query?

Comment: You are checking for the nulls in your where clause, but that is after you have already joined everything. Adding where meta_value IS NOT NULL to each of your joins should fix it. Not sure if there is a fancier way in mysql.

Comment: Add `where ... and entryId is not null`. Also it shouldn't be possible to have multiples rows with null `entryId`. Strictly is not possible for `order_item_id = null` in the subqueries though some systems bend that rule.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried adding the "where meta_value is not null" to each subquery and it ran successfully, however, I'm still seeing numerous NULL rows returned. I'm finding that it has to do with the fact that there are entryID rows without names, emails, addresses, etc. and instead they only contain values for the _product_id, _line_subtotal, _line_total, etc. I'm going to try seeing if I can group them by the _original_order_id as that seems to be the commonality amongst each order.

Comment: Actual that filter I mentioned would belong on the main query. Also note the column to filter on is the group column `entryId`.

Comment: Noticing the `limit 1` everywhere it does appear that you do need to order the results as well. If you're get a null on the first column though, that has nothing to do with the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but perhaps something structured like this would be better for your needs.

```
SELECT oim.order_item_id AS entryId
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE meta_key WHEN "Name" THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS `Full Name`
   , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE meta_key WHEN "Email" THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS `User Email`
   [, etc....]
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim
GROUP BY entryId
ORDER BY entryId
;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT`, like most aggregate functions, ignores null values (the result becoming null only if all values encountered are null).

As for filtering out completely null results; you're looking for `HAVING`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for a more efficient way to put together the data than using subqueries.

Comment: You could have also joined the table to itself multiple times (`ON t1.order_item_id = t0.order_item_id AND t1.meta_key = "Blah1"`), but that likely would've been almost as inefficient as the subquery version.